# Jodatime not using 0 prefixes for Days and Months? Java

Tags: java, jodatime

All,

I created a function to create a Date string from a Joda DateTime object.

```
    public static String getDateString(DateTime dT)
{
    String dateString = dT.getDayOfMonth() + "-";
    dateString = dateString + dT.getMonthOfYear() + "-";
    dateString = dateString + dT.getYear() + " ";
    dateString = dateString + dT.getHourOfDay() + ":";
    dateString = dateString + dT.getMinuteOfHour() + ":" + dT.getSecondOfMinute();
    logger.finer("Date String is : " + dateString);
    return dateString;
}
```

The problem is for days and months with a zero before it e.g. 08th of October, is being printed as

> 8-11-2013 12:51:49

This then breaks my formatting when I read this value the next time I execute my program as it is expecting

I need the format to be explicitly DD-MM-YYYY

With correct output as follows

> 08-11-2013 12:51:49

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) instead of doing this yourself, e.g.:

```
final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
final String dateString = formatter.print(dT);
```

This will also take care of the `0`-prefix issue you are having.

Comment: Wow that just made my life so much easier!

Comment: No problem! For extra bonus points define the formatter as a `private static final` member variable for reuse.

Answer (score 5):

You can directly access the DateTimeFormatter by passing a date format to the `toString()` method.

```
String dateString = dT.toString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```